# Show that $f(x) = \exp(-1/x^2) \quad |x| > 0,$ and $f^{(k)}(0) = 0 \quad$ for$ \quad k = 0,1,...$ is not analytic

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

In the book of Markushevich, Complex Analysis, at page 10, question 1.5, it is asked to verify that the function 
$$f(x) = \exp(-1/x^2) \quad |x| > 0,$$and
$$f^{(k)}(0) = 0 \quad\text{for} \quad k = 0,1,...$$
is infinitely differentiable, but not analytic.

It also states that $f$ does not satisfy

$$|f^{k}(x)| < M k!$$
in a neighbourhood of $0$, but as far as I can see, the function $f^{1}(x)$ and $f^{2}$ takes zero values around $0$, and for practical reason, I cannot check the higher derivatives, so I would say that $f$ is analytic around zero, but the book states that it is not.

So, how to show that the function does not satisfy the give inequality above ?

Comment: What do you mean by “takes zero values around $0$”?

Comment: The function is not analytic in $0$ as you should see from the result to be proven. This is a well known example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove two things.

**First**:

You need to prove that $f$ is infinitelly differentiable. Clearly, the only problem can occur around $0$. To prove that the function is differentiable, you can prove that, for each $k$, the $k$-th derivative of $f$ for nonzero $x$ is equal to $Q(x)\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ where $Q$ is some rational function. This can easily be done by induction. It should also be clear that $$\lim_{x\to0} Q(x)\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} = 0$$ since $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^n} = 0$$ for all values of $n$.

---

**Second**:

You need to prove $f$ is not infinitelly differentiable. A function is analytic iff its power series is convergent. However, for your $f$, the power series around $0$ is

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x\cdot\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x\cdot \frac{0}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 0 = 0$$

and there is no neighborhood of $0$ at which the power series converges and is equal to $f$. Mind you, the power series converges on $\mathbb R$, it just doesn't converge to $f$. For small nonzero values of $x$, the value of $f(x)$ is **not** equal to $0$.